# JUnit test shows string not equal when should be equal

Tags: java, junit

So, I'm currently doing a JUnit test for saving and loading a save file in JSON format.  However, while saving works without a problem, I keep running to an issue where a string I read in from the file is not kept in the variable I'm writing it to.

```
public void loadSettings(Vector<User> U, String url, String filepath) {
        JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj=parser.parse(new FileReader(filepath));
            JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject) obj;
            url=jsonObject.get("URL").toString();
            //System.out.println(URL);
            JSONArray users=(JSONArray)jsonObject.get("Users");
            Iterator<Object> iter=users.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                String temp1=iter.next().toString();
                Long temp2=(Long)iter.next();
                User n=new User(temp1,temp2.intValue());
                U.addElement(n);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The string in question is the "url" string.  The values for the User class I have are inserted in fine.  I don't know what the problem is, and I've been working on this for hours.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the `url`. Why do you pass in a `url` String and then assign something new to that parameter?

Comment: Java passes its parameters **by Value**.  Whatever changes you make to `url` inside the method will not impact the string you pass to the method.

Answer (score -1):

URL may contains some special characters, you can try like this:

```
URLEncoder.encode("This string has spaces", "UTF-8");
```

then store in the file.

last do this:

```
url = URLDecoder.decode(jsonObject.get("URL").toString(), "UTF-8");
```